# Flutter, can't click on Page 2 when it's on Page 1

Tags: flutter

I have created a `PageView` with 3 pages which have a button for each.
Clicking each button should scroll to that page.

- If it's on Page 2, previous page & next page are both clickable.
- If it's on Page 3, previous page is clickable.
- If it's on Page 1, **next page is not clickable**.

[image]

[image]

Update:
When click the two buttons when it's on page1, here's the RawGestureDetector:

- Tap button on First Page's button when position is on Page1.`TapGestureRecognizer`
  [image]
- Tap button on Second Page's button when position is on Page1.`HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer`
  [image]

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthState>.value(
          notifier: AuthState(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: Strings.logoTitle,
        color: Colors.grey,
        home: _ScrollableSubTitleWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ScrollableSubTitleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const _ScrollableSubTitleWidget();

  @override
  _ScrollableSubTitleWidgetState createState() =>
      _ScrollableSubTitleWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollableSubTitleWidgetState extends State<_ScrollableSubTitleWidget> {
  PageController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.5);
    debugPrint('[+] -- $runtimeType: initWithScrollPosition: ');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _animateToPage(int index) {
    // if (index == _controller.page) return;
    debugPrint(
        '[+] -- $runtimeType: scrollPage: [${_controller.page} => $index] ');
    _controller.animateToPage(
      index,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: PageView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _animateToPage(0);
              },
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('First Tab'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _animateToPage(1);   //<-- issue here
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Second Tab'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _animateToPage(2);
              },
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Third Tab'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I found same issue reported at [PageView with viewportFraction < 1.0 - GestureDetector is not working properly] (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23873) and [Inkwell not working properly with PageView.builder](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27744)