# What's the big green right arrow (-->) mean in DevTools with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, devtools

What's the big green right arrow (-->) mean in DevTools with Flutter?

I guess it's related to the interactable area, but I'm not sure.

[image: screen capture]

The code is the same as in [Flutter, Page two can't click when it's on Page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508079/). Here is the simplified code:

```dart
PageController _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.5);

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: PageView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('First Tab'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Second Tab'),
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Third Tab'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: You might want to share your widget tree if you want to know why the arrows move like this.

Comment: Ah, the code is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508079/, I just think it's second question, so I ask this question.  I'd move simple code of it to here.

Comment: this is done in [RenderSliver#debugPaint](https://www.crossdart.info/p/flutter/0.0.38-dev/src/rendering/sliver.dart.html#line-1193) - it calls `_debugDrawArrow` method twice to draw two parallel green arrows - see the params it is called with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These *green arrows* in the so-called "**Debug Paint**" indicate ***scroll*** views.

The direction of the arrows shows which way the scroll view extends, i.e. the arrows will either point to the right or down.
This will appear for e.g. [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), [`SingleChildScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) etc.

[Learn more](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging) about visual debugging in Flutter.

Comment: @JerryZhou I am not sure about that. I guess it could be an issue with finding out how big the size of the `PageView` is going to be because the later pages have not been rendered yet. If you scroll all the way to the right, you can see that the arrows stop at the end of the last item. I would reckon that you could call it a "bug". For more information, you might want to contact the Flutter team, e.g. via a GitHub issue asking why the arrows "expand".

Comment: I have just read the [https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging), it's only mentioned green arrow related to baseline of content, and yellow arrow related to alignment. looks like not said about any green right arrow related to scroll view.

Comment: @JerryZhou Yes, I saw that the documentation is missing this part. I [created an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34106) for that. However, what I linked is definitely the appropriate section in the documentation. You can add `debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;` to your code and you will see the arrows as well.

Comment: I find it's related to Inkwell area : [Inkwell not working properly with PageView.builder](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27744#issuecomment-462356839).